# Play a sound once in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

I built a Flash site that is being used as a teaching tool. The client would now like to add voiceovers to sections. Is there a way to play a sound once on a movie clip, and if the viewer comes back to that clip then the sound won't play again? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick. I haven't tested this code in Flash but this should get you in the right direction.

```
import flash.net.SharedObject

//Use anything in place of "sounds"
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("sounds");

//Check if the sound has not been played
//Use anything in place of "specificSoundPlayed"
if(so.data.specificSoundPlayed == false)
{
//Play the sound
var snd:Sound = new Sound();
snd.load(new URLRequest("my.mp3"));
snd.play();

//Set the shared object property so we know the sound was played
so.data.specificSoundPlayed = true;
}
```

Comment: This would be used for playing the sound only once even if they close the swf and revisit it on the same computer/browser

Answer (score 1):

I like zachzurn's answer. `SharedObject` is pretty much the only way to store cookie-like data on a machine. But I'd suggest that you also make sure to add the requisite error trapping (like try/catch blocks) because some users (myself included) have set their Flash Player settings to disallow sites from storing shared objects.

If you don't want to depend on `SharedObject`, then you'll probably need to setup some calls in and out of Flash to some other server-side technology. If your site requires users to log in, you may already have some persistent data for users; you could add some service calls which let Flash send and receive data about whether the sound has been played.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a boolean flag to false once the sound has been played once.

```
var flag:Boolean = false;
if(!flag){ 
  flag = true;
  playSound();
}
```

Comment: But if that runs every time the user enters the frame on which the code exists, then flag will always be true every time, and thus the sound will play every time.  This should be handled elsewhere, off the given timeline.

Comment: yeah the flag initialization doesnt happen on the same frame, that was just supposed to illustrate the concept. That first line should go someplace where the application gets initialized, i.e. run only once.